# Using ExecuteReader to return a primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How Do I Find the ID from the first query and return this value so it can be inserted into query2? This is the code that needs done when a user completes a form on front end. I need to populate two tables and they will relate through the ID "StoryID" which is a primary key that is automatically created.

```
protected void Upload2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
        userStoryForm.Visible = false;
        info.Text = "You have successfully added a new user story.";


        String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        String usernameData = username.Text.ToString();
        int captureProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("ProjectID"));
        String storyno = StoryNoTextBox.Text;
        String userstory = StoryTextTextBox.Text;

        //Create connection
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        //open connection
        myConnection.Open();

        String query =  "INSERT INTO UserStories (StoryNo, StoryText, ProductOwner, ProjectID) " + 
                        "VALUES ('" + storyno + "','" + userstory + "','" + usernameData + "','" + captureProjectID + "')" +
                        "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS StoryID;";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

       // Call GetOrdinal and assign value to variable.
       SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        int StoryIDData =  reader.GetOrdinal("StoryID");

        // Use variable with GetString inside of loop.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StoryID={0}", reader.GetString(StoryIDData));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();

        //insert productowner, projectID and storyID into ProductBacklog table
        String query2 = "INSERT INTO ProductBacklog (ProductOwner, ProjectID, StoryID) VALUES ('" + usernameData + "', @returnProjectID,'" + StoryIDData + "')";
        SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(query2, myConnection);
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returnProjectID", captureProjectID);


        //close connection
        myConnection.Close();

    }

}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... OUTPUT Inserted.StoryID VALUES ...` for MS SQL

Answer (score 4):

Most important - use parameters in your SQL command. Never concatenate strings like that. You're asking for an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

```
string query = @"
    INSERT INTO UserStories (StoryNo, StoryText, ProductOwner, ProjectID)
    VALUES (@storyno, @userstory, @usernameData, @captureProjectID)
    SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@storyno", DbType.String).Value = storyno;
...
```

To get the returned id, use `ExecuteScalar()`:

```
int StoryIDData = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also, you don't dispose your resources correctly. If an exception is thrown in the method, the `SQLConnection` will not be closed. You should put it in a `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm still a bit confused. Can I remove the whole executeReader part?

Comment: @Colette Yes, `ExecuteScalar()` is all you need to execute the command and get a single value back.